# Filter.Lte(x=>x.Price, "9") getting wrong results

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am applying the query to get records which are **LessthanOREqual** to 9, Price in MongoDB stored as string.

So whenever I appy filter like this:

```cs
filterDefinition&= Builders<DM.Content>.Filter.Lte(x => x.Price, "9");
```

It will return records less than 9 as well as some with greater than 9.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should use `$lte` comparison operator to compare values in string datatype which is not accurate.

Instead, cast the `price` field to numeric datatype and then compare.

In MongoDB query command:

```
{ $expr: { $lte: [ { $toInt: "$price" }, 9 ] } }
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zga_p6zxvVr)

With MongoDB Compass, you can [export the query to specific language](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/export-query-to-language/). And add the generated `BsonDocument` to `filterDefinition`.

```cs
filterDefinition &= new BsonDocument("$expr", 
    new BsonDocument("$lte", 
        new BsonArray
        {
            new BsonDocument("$toInt", "$price"),
            9
        }));
```

> Sample Data

[image: Sample Data]

> Result

[image: Result]